# menu with while and foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach, while-loop

I am stuck with my current knowledge of PHP. I want to make a menu where the info is stored into a database. What I want to achieve is the following:

```
<?php
$names= array();
$aliases= array();
$items = array();
?>
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($menu, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $names[] = $row['page'];
    $aliases[] = $row['alias'];
    $items[] = $row['item'];
}?>

<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($names as $page_name){
            <a href="*** HERE THE ALIAS CORRESPONDING WITH THE NAME***"><?php echo $page_name;?></a>
        ?>
        *** IF THERE ARE SUB MENU ITEMS, SHOW THEM ***
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="*** ALIAS OF SUB ITEM ****">*** NAME OF SUB ITEM***</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have absolutely no idea if i am on the right pad. The foreach works fine for the names or aliasses only, but i want to sort of combine them. Then i want to check if there is a submenu for the hover, but also set the parent item on class "active".

Since it is hard for me to explain it in English, please ask me any question needed so i can provide more info.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide more information. We don't know what a "submenu" is, or how you expect the page to look like.

Comment: can you please share code with static items on the page? as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need three different arrays, only `$names` array would be enough. Second, change your `while()` loop in the following way,

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($menu, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $names[] = array('page_name' => $row['page'], 'alias' => $row['alias'], 'item' => $row['item']);
}
```

This will create a multidimensional array comprising of name, alias and sub-items.

And finally, display the entire *menu* in the following way,

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($names as $page_array){ ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $page_array['alias']; ?>"><?php echo $page_array['page_name']; ?></a>
            <?php
                if(!empty($page_array['item'])){
                    ?>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo $page_array['item']; ?>"><?php echo $page_array['item']; ?></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <?php
                }
        } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The multidimensional arrays are new to me like this. It is working like a charm. Unfortunally I was on the right way with my other solution, so I won't be implementing it, but the right answer nontheless!

Comment: @Saypontigohe Glad I could help. *Cheers! ;-)*

Answer (score 1):

You are overcomplicating things:

```
<?php 

echo '<div id="menu">
        <ul>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($menu, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $names[] = $row['page'];
    $aliases[] = $row['alias'];
    $items[] = $row['item'];

    echo '<li class="pagename"><a href="'.$row['alias'].'">'.$row['page'].'</a>';

    if ('checkforsubitem') {
        echo '<ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="'.$row['alias_subitem'].'">'.$row['name_of_subitem'].'</a>
                </li>
            </ul>';
    }
}
    echo '</li>
    </ul>
</div>';

?>
```

However, this assumes some things about the submenu-bits. Normally, you would either fetch those items within the same query, and have them available to you via `$row`, but you can also do separate queries for those items based on a connection from the `$row['id']` or something, and pull those subitems that corresponds to that id, and run another `while`-loop around the secondary `<li>`-items.

Comment: I am glad you understood my question. But i am running a similar code right now, an have been told that it is impossible to put the parent on active this way, since the parent does not know if the child is on the active page.

Comment: Eh, what? Either that parent/child relationship needs some work, or there are code-issues or database-issues in the mix. Since you're fetching the whole menu from the database, having relationships should be in the database, and should be no problem to fetch correctly.

Comment: Right now, there is a field called "item" which stores "true" if it is in the menu, or "[name of the parent]" when it is a sub-item. The child knows it has a parent, but the parent does not know it ha a child. Is this a wrong structure in the database then?

Comment: Eh, yes. Each menu item (parent or child) should have an ID - a numerical ID. Then, if you have a child, that chlid gets a link to the parent's ID. For instance you have a column named `is_child` which is a `boolean` (ie, 1 or 0), and then you have a column named `parent_id` which gets the parent's ID in there. That way you can pull all the children via calling `SELECT * FROM menu_table WHERE is_child = 1 AND parent_id = :parentID`. This is database-101.

Comment: right now, that is how it is build. But the thing is, There is nothing stored in the parent to know it has a child. The child has the id of the parent, so it knows where the show. But if you are on the page of the child, i want to have the parent on active.

Comment: Ah, but that can be easily fixed either by using CSS or javascript, I assume, if all you want is a visual representation of the menu being active. Or you can add a `has_child` boolean to the menu-table, which gets set to 1 if the parent has children. However, you'll still need to check for that in the code (something like `if ($row['has_child'] == 1 && 'something here to see if it's active (the shown page) or not')`

Comment: Damn, if it is really that easy I feel kinda dumb by making it so much more complicated. I will try out another way around. Glad to know I was on the right way, but did bad with the change above.